# Internet connection lost until network reset

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I've been having issues with my internet connection, but only when the internet signal itself is somewhat weaker.
I have this on plain Ubuntu 20.04, Linux Mint 20 and PopOS ( haven't tried any others ). And I've tried Kernel versions from 5.0 up to 5.9 just to be safe.

Anyway, what's happening is that ever so often ( at least once every hour or half hour ) while the wifi signal is still alright, the internet connection is lost. It doesn't come back unless I reset the wifi connection. I could even switch networks and move back to the original and it works right away.
The connection itself, while it's working, is fast and with a low ping. Wifi strength is around 75% - 85%.

Now, when I take the same laptop, and go close to the router, it never looses internet connectivity at all.

As for my home setup, I have a Wifi router downstairs, and a Wifi repeater on the same floor as where I'm working. The repeater reports an almost perfect signal with the router. And all other devices ( even this laptop when I switch to Windows ) report no issues at all.

I've had this exact same issue before with a different laptop and older Ubuntu version, and I think it was fixed then with a newer Ubuntu version, or kernel or something, but it's been years, so I'm not sure anymore.

My main hope here is that someone can tell me how best to debug this, and find out what's actually happening.

FYI: I can also connect to the repeater with a LAN cable, but the issue still persists. I thought DNS might be related, but I fixed my DNS to the google servers, and it doesn't do anything.

Anyway, if anyone can point me to the right direction, I'd be much obliged.

EDIT: Here is the requested output showing my hardware

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:0014]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. You wrote a long post but never mentioned the hardware.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just added the output here.

Comment: @waltinator I did that, just couldn't make out anything suggesting why the connection is failing.